# Heroku MFA not set but requested after update

Tags: heroku

I have a Heroku account and didn't set a multi factor authentication.
Now I tried to log in and it won't let me without the multi factor authentication. Did they add it automatically?
What can I do?

"Starting January 10, 2023, users will receive an MFA challenge each time they log in. If a user hasn’t already registered for MFA, they’ll be prompted to do so before they can get access to the Heroku Dashboard and CLI."

- Heroku email on Dec 6, 2022

"Verification Method Added

This verification method was recently added to your account:
EMAIL

Authenticator App"

- Heroku email on
  Wed, Dec 7, 6:48 AM - I HAVEN'T ADDED NOTHING PERSONALLY

Answer (score 0):

The other person that had access to the account just remembered that he added a MFA.
He gave me the code and I was able to successfully login.